# scss @each Adjacent sibling

Tags: sass

I've always wanted to know if this can be done with sass.

Using @each or @for, repeat adjacent selectors for a count of what I chose.

So the output is

```
.class{
    opacity: 1;

    & + .class{
        opacity: 0.8;

        & + .class{
            opacity: 0.6;

            & + .class{
                opacity: 0.4;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Can this be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're asking for is a fairly simple loop to generate the desired selector:

```
$opacity: 1, .8, .6, .4;
$sel: '';
@each $o in $opacity {
    $sel: if($sel == '', '.class', $sel + ' + .class');
    #{$sel} {
        opacity: $o;
    }
}
```

Alternately:

```
$siblings: 4;
$step: .2;
$class: '.class';
$sel: '';
@for $i from 0 to $siblings {
    $sel: if($sel == '', '.class', $sel + ' + .class');
    #{$sel} {
        opacity: 1 - (1 * ($step * $i));
    }
}
```

Comment: Fantastic. I think your alternative is what i'm looking for. Being able to define everything so it's easier to understand for other.